# Laravel mix, unable locate mix file: /css/xxxxx.css during npm run production

Tags: laravel, webpack

When I finished my task, I didn't commit webpack packaged assets such like CSS, JS, only commit `/resources/assets/*` to git, and pull the commits on the production machine, during it packing js and CSS it needs a little time to minify CSS and js.

At this time many user request the page, and some page include CSS such like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/xxxxx.css') }}"/>`
 will cause an exception in the log like `Unable to locate Mix file: /css/xxxxx.css`

How can I avoid this happened?

Comment: How do you deploy the code? Do you use Laravel Forge? I don't know your deploying setup and your possibilities.
You can write a deployment script and toggle Laravel with "php artisan down" to a maintenance mode. When your webpack task is ready and your application is build in production mode then you can run "php artisan up" to end the maintenance mode. 
Only an idea ;-)

Comment: Hi @LukasR. I just use GCP Compute Engine's virtual machine, and manually pull the code, if some assets need packaging just manually run `$ npm run production`.

Comment: As already mentioned, you could create an "deploy.sh" script on your GCP virtual mashine. Hear you can find a tutorial from the Linux Foundation: https://www.linux.com/learn/writing-simple-bash-script

Possible script (not tested):

'#!/bin/bash
cd /your/project/path
git pull origin master
composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
echo "" | sudo -S service php7.2-fpm reload
if [ -f artisan ]
then
    php artisan migrate --force
    php artisan down
fi
npm install && npm run production
if [ -f artisan ]
then
    php artisan up
fi'

Comment: Hi @LukasR. thank you for your comment.
I am being used to manually git pull && npm run production and sometimes need composer install, I just don't want during npm run production, user see some error page or maintain mode page. I don't want downtime, is there any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Running `composer install` or `npm run prod` on a production server which is not in maintenance mode is not adviced. If you need a zero-downtime deployment, take a look at [Envoyer](https://envoyer.io/). It's made by the same person who created Laravel.

On a side note, running `npm run prod` on a production server is **not adviced**, even if you use envoyer. There is no point in having all your node files on the server and you'll be wasting unnecessary server processing power by running node commnds. I'd recommend running node commands on your local machine and pushing the final compiled files that webpack spits out to the server. Anyways, you need to check if the production version of your CSS and JS work as intended on our local machine before deploying it to the server.